# $_POST global empty when uploading a file using HttpWebRequest in C#

Tags: c#, php, post, httpwebrequest

I have a c# function that is used to upload a file to a PHP web service. The PHP web service is expecting the following

- A POST parameter called UploadFileRequestDto containing some XML data
- The File stream

For some odd reason the $_POST parameter contains the UploadFileRequestDto only some of the time. If I look at the contents of

```
file_get_contents("php://input"))
```

I can see that the request is comming through as expected with the UploadFileRequestDto included.

Doing a

```
print_r($_REQUEST)
```

is returning an empty array.

Can anyone help me with a solution to this problem, my C# function is stipulated below

```
public string UploadFile(UploadFileRequestDto uploadFileRequestDto,string fileToUpload, string fileUploadEndpoint)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fileUploadEndpoint);
            request.ReadWriteTimeout = 1000 * 60 * 10;
            request.Timeout = 1000 * 60 * 10;
            request.KeepAlive = false;

            var boundary = "B0unD-Ary";

            request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
            request.Method = "POST";

            var postData = "--" + boundary + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;";
            postData += "name=\"UploadFileRequestDto\"\r\n\r\n";
            postData += string.Format("{0}\r\n", SerializeUploadfileRequestDto(uploadFileRequestDto));
            postData += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";

            postData += "--" + boundary + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data;name=\"file\";filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload) + "\"\r\n";
            postData += "Content-Type: multipart/form-data\r\n\r\n";

            var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            byte[] boundaryBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");

            byte[] filedata = null;
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(fileToUpload)))
            {
                filedata = reader.ReadBytes((int)reader.BaseStream.Length);
            }

            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length + filedata.Length + boundaryBytes.Length;
            request.GetRequestStream().Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            request.GetRequestStream().Write(filedata, 0, filedata.Length);
            request.GetRequestStream().Write(boundaryBytes, 0, boundaryBytes.Length);

            var response = request.GetResponse();
            var data = response.GetResponseStream();
            var sReader = new StreamReader(data);
            var sResponse = sReader.ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();

            return sResponse.TrimStart(new char[] { '\r', '\n' });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogProvider.Error(string.Format("OzLib.Infrastructure : WebHelper : public string UploadFile(UploadFileRequestDto uploadFileRequestDto, string fileUploadEndpoint) : Exception = {0}", ex.ToString()));
        }
```

Comment: How is the PHP web service running? Is it behind a web server such as Apache or Nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the problem, the

```
post_max_size
```

setting in the php.ini was set to 8M and some of the files I was trying to upload exeeded 8M. Changed this setting to 16M and restarted the PHP service.

When the file size exeeds the limit that was set the $_POST global is empty.